# How to cite an item with a parallel Ancient Greek title?

Tags: biblatex

```
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc},
    \usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
    \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{myfile.bib}

    @Book{TH,
    title = {The theory of Havens = Θεορια τον μετεωρον},
    language = {english}, %then error. -> \textgreek{Θεορια τον μετεωρον}?
    }

    \end{filecontents}

    \addbibresource{myfile.bib}

    \begin{document}

    Test.\cite{TH}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: There is the field `origtitle`, but the manual says it is not used by the standard styles, so you have to add support for it.

Comment: What is the exact output you are looking for for the bibliography entry?

Comment: Just "The theory of Havens = Θεορια τον μετεωρον" or The theory of Havens (Θεορια τον μετεωρον).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple approach of writing

```
title = {The theory of Havens = Θεορια τον μετεωρον},
```

fails for exactly the same reason that just writing

```
The theory of Havens = Θεορια τον μετεωρον
```

in your document fails: The language (and in particular the font encoding) is not switched properly.

The easy way out is to switch the language explicitly (like you would in the document).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{th,
  title = {The theory of Havens = \foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{Θεορια τον μετεωρον}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{th}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The bibliography shows "The theory of Havens = Θεορια τον μετεωρον"]

---

If you are also looking for a way to make the input more semantic, you could try the `origtitle` field as suggested by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474388/how-to-cite-an-item-with-a-parallel-ancient-greek-title#comment1197028_474388). Note that for most intents and purposes the `orig...` field have been superseded by the `related` features, but here it might make sense. The standard styles don't print that field by default, so we have to modify a few things to get it to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
  \setunit{\addspace=\space}%
  \printfield{origtitle}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{titleaddon}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{th,
  title     = {The theory of Havens},
  origtitle = {\foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{Θεορια τον μετεωρον}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{th}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It could be a nice idea to try and switch the language of the `origtitle` field based on the `origlanguage` information, but `origlanguage` is a list now, so that becomes tricky.

Alternatively, you could look into `titleaddon`, which is used in all standard styles and therefore available without additional modification.